# entity framework - inheritance

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I have  Entity Framework Models similar to :

```
Category
Content
NewsCategory (Inherits Category)
News ( Inherits Content)
```

I use TPH inheritance for both newscategory and news . I have a TYPE field in my DB. if type=1 means News ( in content table) and again if type=1 means ( in NewsCategory table).

category and cntent have many to many relationship!

but when I want to add news how can I prevent to add news with other type ?

when I add a news it want categoryId and I can use 1,2 or other Id!

#

if fact I want to create many to many relation ship between news and news category AND category and content . and I want news dont know any thing about content and its relation ship

Answer (score 0):

Database doesn't understand meaning of TPH inheritance - it has many-to-many association between Categories and Contents table and it indeed allows creating relation between any category and content. You cannot avoid it in TPH on database level but on entity level you should have navigation properties only in your derived types so handling it on application level should be straight forward.

Comment: a world of thanks. in my case both content and category have TYPE. for ex : content type can be news and category type can be news. how can I add a news and  prevent to add other category type to that news?

Answer (score 0):

I tend to define enums to accompany the inheritance classes I define.

```
public enum CategoryType
{
    News = 1,
    Photography,
    PopularMusic
}

public enum ContentType
{
    Article = 1,
    Image,
    Video 
}
```

You two tables could have a TypeId and so when your code writes a news item.

```
Category.TypeId = (int)CategoryType.News;
```

and

```
Content.TypeId = (int)ContentType.Article;
```

You can't avoid having to do this is code, but it should be clearer and less error prone that just throwing an INT value at a typeId filed.

In your case I'm not sure of your relationships, such as where the Type field is (I assumed there'e one in Category and also one in Content). You seem to have missed something when you wrote `type=1 means ( in NewCategory table)` in you question.

I'm not sure why you would need to add a categoryId when adding a news as news inherits from Content and not Category did you mean TypeId?

Comment: a world of thanks. I my case news category and news have m-m relationship and Articles and articleCategory have m-m relashionship.